# How do I set up an email address without Emails in cPanel

Tags: cpanel

I keep seeing that setting up an email address for your domain is very easy in cPanel, however I'm using cPanel 62.0.8 and I don't have "Email Accounts" listed anywhere. Even searching "email" and "emails" doesn't show me a usable result. What can I do? I believe this was there before but I had my paid web host delete/recreate my account due to a sudden problem with Softaculous where I couldn't download anything. I'm still getting that same Softaculous error post-recreation (sigh) AND I've apparently lost "Email Accounts".

My Account [image: commercial photography locations]

Guide's Account [image: commercial photography locations]

Comment: sounds like time to find a new host

Answer (score 1):

If it is your server, log into WHM and then Feature Manager and make sure Email Accounts is enabled for the profile you are using.

If it isn't your server, you will have to speak to your hosting company